# Error in using aggregate function max() oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to run query

```
select * from OS_Historystep where step_name = '011' and finish_date = max(finish_date) ;
```

But i am getting error that

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 72
```

what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate in a `where` clause. Also, you can't mix non-aggregated data and aggregated data from the same column in a single select. You'll need to use a sub-query:

```
select * 
from OS_Historystep hs1
where step_name = '011' 
and finish_date = (select max(finish_date) 
                   from OS_Historystep hs2 
                   where hs2.step_name = hs1.step_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot reference an aggregate like that. you would either have to put a sub query up like below (assuming you wanted the `max(finish_date)` to mean the max finish date for step 011 and not the max finish date in the whole table (which may return no rows):

```
select * 
  from OS_Historystep 
 where step_name = '011' 
   and finish_date = (select max(finish_date) 
                        from OS_Historystep
                       where step_name = '011');
```

or use an analytic function

```
select *
  from (select s.*, rank() over (partition by step_name order by finish_date desc) rnk
          from OS_Historystep s
         where step_name = '011')
 where rnk = 1;
```